# Getting multiple errors compiling Java code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to programming, and I'm using Eclipse to make some easy programs like calculators and vote counting. (Don't mind the language, it's Portuguese and i'm from Brazil.)

So as you can see in the image with "Questão1.java." Class opened compiles perfectly, and the "Questão2.java" shows quite a lot of errors, and I have absolutely no idea what it means.

This one is giving a lot of errors:

[image: This one is giving a lot of errors]

This one compiles perfectly, no errors and results as expected:

[image: This one compiles perfectly, no errors and results as expected.]

Thanks everyone for answering, i found out the error and it was indeed the "printf"...and also i'll remember to never post codes as images next time, again thank you guys.

Comment: Please don't post your code as images. Include it in the actual post for future reference.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To attract more people to answer, please include your source code in the question text as well as the error message.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll make sure to remember that in the future, thank you for the attention, really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `printf()` instead of `print()` or `println()`.

`printf()` adds formatting to whatever you are trying to print, and the String that determines how your output should be formatted uses characters like `%`, which you also use in the class that throws errors.

The error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ' '
    at [and so on...]
    at Questao2_Lista[bla bla bla].main(Questao2.java:18)
```

can be read in the following way:

The first line defines what kind of exception was thrown, in this instance it is an "UnknownFormatConversionException".

The lines below it are called a "stacktrace", that show where exactly the exception was thrown and the "way" it got propagated up the call-stack.

It looks like this is the only error, I can't see any of the other errors you talked about so I guess you just assumed that every line was a separate error?

Comment: Yeah i actually thought it was multiple errors, i can see that it was only one now, thank you and thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "Questão2.java" is the System.out.printf statement. The statement has a '%' which is a special character. % is used as a preceding character for a place holder

Eg: %d in the string will be replaced with a number passed as an argument.

```
int lines =10;
System.out.printf ("There are %d lines", lines);
```

Will come as:

```
There are 10 lines
```

If its just a print statement Use System.out.println instead of System.out.printf

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `System.out.print()` or `System.out.println()` instead `System.out.printf()` in line 18 of Questão2.java